# Java Annotation mulitple value , no array

Tags: java, annotations

i've got a a question i hope you can help me.
I want to create a Annotation for my little little database framework but how can i create this with a annotation?

```
@Columns({name="id", type="long"},{name="username",type="string"})
```

Simple annotation ca have a String[] butt i want a key/value in this array.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

more annotations of same type aren't allowed，you can change a total realization of ideas

```
public @interface Column {
      String name();
      String type();
}
public @interface Columns {
    Column[] value();
}

@Columns({@Column(name="id", type="long"), @Column(name="username",type="string")})
public void test() {}
```

Comment: Yes thats fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create the annotation class that itself holds a key-value pair. Then, use it as parameter to another annotation that accepts array. Would be something like

```
 @Columns(columns =
   @Column{name = "name", type = "type"},
   @Column{name = "name", type = "type"}, 
   @Column{name = "name", type = "type"}
 )
```

See Hibernate [@SecondaryTable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTable.html) for inspiration.